# VS-Code and Python - problems with Getting Started Tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The tutorial says to ask questions here, so I am.

I successfully installed the python extension from MS into VS-code 1.56.2.   I've been following https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial  step by step.
For me, it works until

[image: From Getting Started]

All steps above here work just fine.  Then everything stops.
What seems to be happening is that things in VS, like a Jupyter terminal are using a different python install that the one you get if you open a Terminal -wsl in subsequent steps.

Jupyter terminal can import PIP items and all that while in wsl pip doesn't even show as installed. And it resists any attempts to install pip.  I cant run the py command in a terminal, it fails. I can run python3.8 in wsl and get that interpreter prompt.

I'm thinking the disconnect is that terminal wsl should be pointing at the python that wsl installed since it works... right?  In any case i'm real confused as I cant even make it through the first page of instructions here...
Thanks.

Comment: are you running `py` on windows with a virtual environment on windows or are you running `python3` on wsl linux with a virtual environment there?

Comment: why capture the website when a simple link to the header is enough, use the `#` when you hover the header

Comment: python3 on wsl2 ubuntu linux.  I dont really understand the other comment.